# How to retrieve all consecutive items from a Key Value Pair List?

Tags: c#, list, linq

Here's the list. At the end we got to have 6 items in it.

```
List<KeyValuePair<Element, int» myList = new List<KeyValuePair<Element, int»();
```

This does not work:

```
           foreach (KeyValuePair<Element, int> i in myList)

                if (i.Value - [i- 1].Value == 1)
                {
                     //
                }
```

This one either. It gives only one item:

```
 List<KeyValuePair<Element, int>> filteredList = new List<KeyValuePair<Element, int>>();
           

        for (int i = 1; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((myList[i].Value - myList[i - 1].Value) == 1)
            {
                    filteredList.Add(myList[i - 1]);
            }
        }
```

This is how list looks like now:

```
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 2], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 2], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 2], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 2], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 2], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 2], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 7], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 7], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 7], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 7], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 7], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 7], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 8], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 8], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 8], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 8], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 8], 
[Autodesk.Revit.DB.Architecture.Room, 8]
```

Comment: Given "the way the list looks now," only returning one item is the correct result.  There's only one place in your list where the `Value` changes by exactly 1, and it's where you go from 7 to 8.  If that's not the result you're expecting, can you explain the requirements a bit more clearly?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for something like [MoreLinq.GroupAdjacent](https://morelinq.github.io/2.7/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_GroupAdjacent.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner solution using Linq:

```
var filtered = myList.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).Distinct().Select(v => myList.First(kvp => kvp.Value == v)).ToList();
```

Keep in mind, this solution is O(N^2), and the problem can easily be solved O(N) but that shouldn't matter given the size of your list.

Here is a more human-readable solution that is O(N):

```
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Room>();
    foreach (var (key,value) in myList)
    {
        if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(value)) dictionary[value] = key;
    }

    var filtered = dictionary.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<Room, int>(kvp.Value, kvp.Key)).ToList();
```